# Carrossel multi itens dinamico usando bootstrap

Tags: php, html5, bootstrap-3, carousel

Estou com problemas ao fazer um carrossel multi itens dinâmico com apenas duas  colunas **bootstrap**, quando eu informa a quantidade de colunas no caso **col-md-6** os itens quebram e são exibidos em mais uma linha abaixo, alguém poderia me auxiliar?

Como deve ficar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue um exemplo com 3 colunas: https://www.bootply.com/94444

Comment: Você pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código que gera esse comportamento citado?

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss eu deixei um link do exemplo abaixo, este está com 3 colunas eu gostaria apenas de 2 colunas como na imagem.

Comment: O link é de um exemplo, não da sua página. Coloque o código que você fez tentando deixar em duas colunas.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu ainda não criei essa parte porque estava justamente com essa dúvida de como fazer esse carrossel com duas colunas a imgem em anexo é apenas do PSD, o exemplo que passei o link é justamente o que preciso so precisarei adaptar tirando uma seta e invez de imagem o conteudo e dar um espaçamento na seta.

Comment: Então como concluiu que definindo as colunas com `col-md-6` ocorre a quebra de linha? Você não fez o código para testar isso?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss fiz sim mas não postei o código que faz com que as colunas quebrem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde!

Acho que poderia ser feito dessa forma. As mudanças foram simples.

```js
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
});
```

```css
/* override position and transform in 3.3.x */
.carousel-inner .item.left.active {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.carousel-inner .item.right.active {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

.carousel-inner .item.next {
  transform: translateX(50%)
}
.carousel-inner .item.prev {
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.carousel-inner .item.right,
.carousel-inner .item.left { 
  transform: translateX(0);
}


.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {background-image:none;}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/CCCCCC/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee/fff&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4/fff&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: como é que eu faço para adicionar mais colunas em vez de só duas?